# Camera view different from the result image

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an iPad app that takes a picture and blends it with a frame choose by the user. My problem is that the camera view shows more of the image that it will be use on the frame, because it will be cut and resized to fit the frame.

I tried to set the camera view to be the size of the photo inside of the frame, but the frames resolution are too high and bigger than the iPad screen.

I'm also coping the picture to fit the frame, if I don't do it the image get's a shrunk fill. So what I am trying to do is to make the camera show only what won't be cropped.

This is my crop method:

```
func crop(image: UIImage, width: Double, height: Double) -> UIImage {

        let cgimage = image.cgImage!
        let contextImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimage)
        let contextSize: CGSize = contextImage.size
        var posX: CGFloat = 0.0
        var posY: CGFloat = 0.0
        var cgwidth: CGFloat = CGFloat(width)
        var cgheight: CGFloat = CGFloat(height)

        // See what size is longer and create the center off of that
        if contextSize.width > contextSize.height {
            posX = ((contextSize.width - contextSize.height) / 2)
            posY = 0
            cgwidth = contextSize.height
            cgheight = contextSize.height
        } else {
            posX = 0
            posY = ((contextSize.height - contextSize.width) / 2)
            cgwidth = contextSize.width
            cgheight = contextSize.width
        }

        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: cgwidth, height: cgheight)

        // Create bitmap image from context using the rect
        let imageRef: CGImage = cgimage.cropping(to: rect)!

        // Create a new image based on the imageRef and rotate back to the original orientation
        let image: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)

        return image
    }
```

This is how I set up the camera, the prviewView is the camera view:

```
  guard let frontCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .front)
            else {
                fatalError("Front camera not found")
        }
        var error: NSError?
        var input: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
        do{
            input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamera)
        }catch let error1 as NSError{
            error = error1
            input = nil
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
        if error == nil && session!.canAddInput(input) {
            session!.addInput(input)
            if session!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput!){
                session!.addOutput(stillImageOutput!)                
                videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session!)
                videoPreviewLayer!.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
                var videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: 1)
                switch deviceOrientation {
                case .portrait:
                    videoOrientation = .portrait
                    break
                case .portraitUpsideDown:
                    videoOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
                    break
                case .landscapeRight:
                    videoOrientation = .landscapeLeft
                    break
                case .landscapeLeft:
                    videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
                    break
                default:
                    break
                }
                videoPreviewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = videoOrientation ?? .portrait
                previewView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { 
                    self.session!.startRunning()
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.videoPreviewLayer!.frame = self.previewView.bounds
                    }
                }                
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a stupid mistake I made passing the wrong sizes of the original image. Everything was working correctly in the function.